# unowned listening socket on linux

Tags: linux-networking

As root, `netstat -tnlp4e` includes a few listening sockets with no owner.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58245           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9578        -
```

`lsof -n -i :58245` returns nothing.

The following search also finds nothing:

```
for D in $(ls -1 /proc); do 
  if [ -d $D -a -d "$D/fd" ];then 
    ls -l $D/fd/ | grep 9578
  fi
done
```

I have verified that that search will return the socket listing as I expect for other inode numbers.

I think the kernel listening on a socket will make it not show a PID in netstat, but shouldn't there be other record of this socket/inode?

How do I find what is listening on this socket?

( Ubuntu 14.04, linux 3.13.0-24-generic )

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure in that is the `nfs` kernel module. Stop nfs-kernel-server, umount all nfs shared then the listening port will be disappear.